# Is it acceptable to cut nails, and trim hair and beard on Tuesdays?

Tags: sunnah, source-identification, taharah

Some people say not to cut your nails, or trim your hair and beard on Tuesdays. Is there any hadith or verse in support of this, or is it just a superstition?

Comment: I believe you are from India. Aren't you?

Comment: yes ! i am an proud indian :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: In the name of Allah, Most Beneficent, Most Merciful]

Your profile says that you are from India and this is an Indian tradition followed by Hindus for ages.

Let me assure you that there is no day that Islam considers inauspicious for cutting nails or trimming hair. This tradition has penetrated into Indian Muslims through Hinduism.

According to what I know and what I have heard about this tradition is that the Hindus consider this day auspicious.

> **Tuesday = (मंगलवार) Mangalvaar.**
>
> **(मंगल)Mangal = very auspicious.**

On the auspicious day of Mangal (Also the name of Hindu God of war who is very hard to please), they avoid all kinds of nonconstructive works. Cutting nails, trimming hair and shaping beard are just a few to name them.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللَّهُمَّ انْفَعْنِي بِمَا عَلَّمْـتَنِي وَ عَلِّمْنِي مَا يَنْفَعُنِي

Comment: but why even muslim barber shops are closed on tuesdays?

Comment: I repeat again. This tradition has has its roots from Hinduism and some Muslims follow it. Another reason why Muslim barbers shut on Tuesdays (which is not the case everywhere) is perhaps to maintain business-harmony with the Hindu barbers.

Comment: ok tabrez bhai, thanks for the answer now i am accepting it

Comment: And what about cutting hair or nails or beard on the birth day...suppose my birth date day is Thursday so some don't allow me to cut my hair on that day? Is this present in Islam??

Comment: @Zia in Egypt and other Arabic states traditionally barbers and hairdressers close on Monday some say because the fatimide caliphs wanted to cut their hair on this day and invited them to their palaces some say its an import from Europe, I assume that in Morocco it was on Tuesday nobody really knows why. But it seems its a historical weekend or day-off. In Egypt groceries traditionally close on Tuesday, shoemakers on Sunday etc. most of these traditional days-off have vanished now. Note that many craftsmen in where none Muslims (Copts in Egypt, Jews and other Christians elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Cutting nails on Thursday  after aser is good before performing jumma, you clean up your self be prepared  for the of jumma. See how prophet  Muhammad  did all this just follow his sunna, we dont need hinduo or budda practice here, be sure of what you do.you are answerable for your act.

May Allah guide us and protect  us all.